# Getting Ubuntu 12.04.2 to show GUI interface after installing it as a VM in XenServer 6.1

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualization

After installing Ubuntu 12.04.2 within as a VM on XenServer 6.1 I only have the command line interface. I have tried running the following commands to install that GUI and it stated that it was install successfully. However, after the reboot the GUI did not show.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

After reboot only the command line shows up.
How can I get the GUI to show up?

Comment: Maybe first install xorg: sudo apt-get install xorg

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command at the CLI:

```
startx
```